# Flask App Dispatching: Multiple uWSGI instances or dispatch to single instance.

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I'm working on a Flask application, in which we will have multiple clients (10-20) each with their own configuration (for the DB, client specific settings etc.) Each client will have a subdomain, like www.client1.myapp.com, www.cleint2.myapp.com. I'm using uWSGI as the middleware and nginx as the proxy server.

There are a couple of ways to deploy this I suppose, one would be to use [application dispatching](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/appdispatch/), and a single instance of uwsgi. Another way would be to just run a separate  uwsgi instance for each client, and forward the traffic with nginx based on subdomain to the right app. Does anyone know of the pros and cons of each scenario? Just curious, how do applications like Jira handle this?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend having multiple instances, forwarded to by nginx.  I'm doing something similar with a PHP application, and it works very well.

The reason, and benefit of doing it this way is that you can keep everything completely separate, and if one client's setup goes screwy, you can re-instance it and there's no problem for anyone else.  Also, no user, even if they manage to break the application level security can access any other user's data.

I keep all clients on their own databases (one mysql instance, multiple dbs), so I can do a complete sqldump (if using mysql, etc) or for another application which uses sqlite rather than mysql: copy the .sqlite database completely for backup.

Going this way means you can also easily set up a 'test' version of a client's site, as well as as live one.  Then you can swap which one is actually live just by changing your nginx settings. Say for doing upgrades, you can upgrade the testing one, check it's all OK, then swap. (Also, for some applications, the client may like having their own 'testing' version, which they can break to their hearts content, and know they (or you) can reinstance it in moments, without harming their 'real' data).

Going with application dispatching, you cannot easily get nginx to serve separate client upload directories, without having a separate nginx config per client (and if you're doing that, then why not go for individual uWSGI instances anyway).  Likewise for individual SSL certificates (if you want that...).

Each subdomain (or separate domain entirely for some) has it's own logging, so if a certain client is being DOS'd, or hacked otherwise, it's easy to see which one.

You can set up file-system level size quotas per user, so that if one client starts uploading gBs of video, your server doesn't get filled up as well.

The way I'm working is using ansible to provision and set up the server how I want it, with the client specific details kept in a separate host_var file.  So my inventory is:

```
[servers]
myapp.com #or whatever...

[application_clients]
apples
pears
elephants

[application_clients:vars]
ansible_address=myapp.com
```

then `host_vars/apples`:

```
url=apples.myapp.com
db_user=apples
db_pass=secret
```

then in the provisioning, I set up a two new users & one group for each client.  For instance: `apples`, `web.apples` as the two users, and the group simply as `apples` (which both are in).

This way, all the application code is owned by `apples` user, but the PHP-FPM instance (or uWSGI instance in your case) is run by `web.apples`.  The permissions of all the code is `rwXr-X---`, and the permissions of uploads & static directories is `rwXrwXr-X`.  Nginx runs as it's own user, so it can access ONLY the upload/static directories, which it can serve as straight files.  Any private files which you want to be served by the uWSGI app can be set that way easily.  The `web` user can read the code, and execute it, but cannot edit it.  The actual user itself can read and write to the code, but isn't normally used, except for updates, installing plugins, etc.

I can give out a SFTP user to a client which is chroot'd to their uploads directory if they want to upload outside of the application interface.

Using ansible, or another provisioning system, means there's very little work needed to create a new client setup, and if a client (for whatever reason) wants to move over to their own server, it's just a couple of lines to change in the provisioning details, and re-run the scripts.  It also means I can keep a development server installed with the exact same provisioning as the main server, and also I can keep a backup amazon instance on standby which is ready to take over if ever I need it to.

I realise this doesn't exactly answer your question about pros and cons each way, but it may be helpful anyway.  Multiple instances of uWSGI or any other WSGI server (mainly I use waitress, but there are plenty of good ones) are very simple to set up and if done logically, with a good provisioning system, easy to administrate.

Comment: This is basically what I was thinking, the only downside to the multiple uwsgi instance setup is perhaps memory usage. Its not really an issue for me, with only a couple dozen clients, but I suppose it could be if you had say, hundreds or thousands of clients.

Comment: If you have hundreds of clients, you can probably afford more than one server. :-)  Also, you'll need to be even more security conscious, as you will almost certainly start picking up bad guys.